# AVAudioPlayer makes system sound louder when played at the same time

Tags: objective-c, avaudioplayer

I've already asked this question before and even set a bounty but it still remains unanswered. Please someone help me out!!
[System sound becomes louder when AVAudioPlayer is initiated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37436868/5184188)

I play sound effects such as button clicking sounds etc with SystemSound and background music with AVAudioPlayer. When AVAudioPlayer starts while SystemSound is being played, that particular system sound becomes like 5 times louder all of a sudden. Has anyone else experienced that? What could be the fix?

These are in SoundControl.m and I'm playing gameBG right after transition.

```
-(void)gameBG {

self.sharedSoundControl = [SoundControl sharedSoundControl];
if (self.sharedSoundControl.musicOff == NO) {
    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"bgm" withExtension:@"mp3"] error:nil];
    self.audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
    self.audioPlayer.volume = 0.3f;
        [self.audioPlayer play];
}}

-(void)transition {

if (self.sharedSoundControl.effectOff == NO) {

NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"transition" ofType:@"caf"];
SystemSoundID soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath], &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}}
```

Comment: I would guess it happens due to the mixing.  You many not have any options except filing an enhancement request with Apple.

Comment: But I'm sure there's a solution to this because millions of mobile games out there are doing it EXCEPT.. they only use AVAudioPlayer even for super short sounds which would seem like an overkill.

Comment: Perhaps this is one reason for doing so.  Another reason, of course, is to have a single process for playing sounds.  It's less complicated, even if there are no other benefits.

Comment: But then again, if this has no "real solution" and turns out that AVAudioPlayer and System Sound cannot be used at the same time because of what I'm experiencing, then System Sound is completely useless... I bet almost all apps are in need of AVAudioPlayer hence System Sound only causes problems.

Comment: I don't think it's fair that because an API doesn't work for you that it must be useless.  A lot of apps don't play audio as their main function, but may want to play the occasional sound to alert users that something has happened.